# Vim is NOT indenting by spaces

Tags: vim, indentation

I have a file that is set to indent by four spaces. I have a block of code that looks something like:

```
content
    content
end
```

You can see how everything above is 4 spaces in. Vim likes to do something like:

```
content
    content
      new line #(2 spaces, not 4)
end
```

I set up my vimrc file to have the following lines, in addition to the default settings:

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

What's going on? Even if I do `1>>` it moves too far over and `1<<` moves to far left.

Comment: I did. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: What is the `filetype`?

Comment: A couple of things to check... in vim, while editing that file, `:set` and see what tabstop, shiftwidth and expandtab are set to.  (Just to make sure that they are loaded from your .vimrc correctly).  Also, you could try setting `softtabstop=4` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `set cindent` to your vimrc and see effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think `smartindent` is depreciated.  Try `cindent` for C-style languages.  You could also try `filetype indent on`.